add an apostrophe to equation number having a distant scope
I want to add apostrophe to equation which is not in front of one number.
I referred
Adding an apostrophe in subequations numbering/lettering
but this was not able to solve my problem.
I paste my latex code. I would like you to figure out my problem with it.
Let's think about the meaning of following equation

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
        (S): \quad a x+b y+c z=d
    \end{equation}

The equation of the plane $\left(S_0\right)$, which is parallel to this plane and passes through the origin, is 

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:14}
        \left(S_0\right): \quad a x+b y+c z=0.
    \end{equation}


Let         

    \[
        \boldsymbol{a}=\left(\begin{array}{l}
            a \\
            b \\
            c
        \end{array}\right), \quad \boldsymbol{x}=\left(\begin{array}{l}
            x \\
            y \\
            z
        \end{array}\right)
        \]
        
Then,equation(\ref{eq:13}),(\ref{eq:14}) is respectively

        \[
        \begin{array}{ll}
            (S): & (\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x})=d \\ % I want to add (\ref{eq:13}) with apostrophe
            \left(S_0\right): & (\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x})=0 %I want to add (\ref{eq:14})　with apostrophe
        \end{array}
        \]
        
and this equation(\ref{eq:14'})...


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Just out of idle curiosity: Why do write \left(S_0\right) instead of -- simply and correctly -- (S_0)?

I'm using  mathpix's snip(image recognition). so as long as it doesn't bother me in reading with pdf , I don't change latex code. Thus there are some weird codes. But while compiling latex,  no problem.

If you care about fine math typesetting, you should avoid needlessly employing \left and \right.

Something like this?

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}.   % for 'align' environment and '\tag' macro
\usepackage{bm}         % for '\bm' macro; don't use '\boldsymbol' needlessly

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{12} % just for this example

\begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
(S)   \quad ax + by + cz = d
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:14}
(S_0) \quad ax + by + cz = 0
\end{equation}

We have
\[
    \bm{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
        a \\ b \\ c
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad 
    \bm{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\begin{align}
(S)\quad   & (\bm{a},\bm{x})=d 
   \tag{$\ref{eq:13}'$} \label{eq:13prime}\\
(S_0)\quad & (\bm{a},\bm{x})=0 
   \tag{$\ref{eq:14}'$} \label{eq:14prime}
\end{align}

Then, equation \eqref{eq:14prime} \dots
\end{document}


This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

If you don't mind, I'd like to ask you
1.how did you come up with this solution. Did you refer documentation or something?
2.why should I  avoid needlessly employing \left and \right.
3.why should I use '\bm' instead of '\boldsymbol'.
I'd like to know for the future.

@studing - I’ve been using LaTeX for more than 30 years — I guess I’ve picked up various skills along the way. Blindly auto-sizing all delimiters is lazy and will sooner or later (usually, sooner) lead to unexpected and unpleasant results. \bm is shorter and more general than \boldsymbol.

Thank you for brief and convinved explanation from your seasoned experience! I'm going to check it, while writing with Tex.

I'd make a few fixes to your code, besides adding the “variant equation numbers”.

Don't rely on current equation numbers when defining a \label

\left(\begin{array}{l}...\end{array}\right) is more simply \begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}, with better spacing and centered symbols.

\bm is better than \boldsymbol, generally speaking, and much easier to type.

\left(S_0\right) should be (S_0).

(\ref{label}) should better be \eqref{label}.


A point to note: if you load hyperref, the constructions
\tag{\ref{eq:...})

should become
\tag{\ref*{eq:...})

so an unwanted hyperlink wouldn't be created.
With \intertext you can get alignment across text in the middle.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{bm} % load this after math font packages

\makeatletter
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\textprime}{}{%
  \@inmathwarn\textprime\mbox{\m@th$'$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Let's think about the meaning of following equation
\begin{alignat}{2}
  (S): &\quad& a x+b y+c z=d \label{eq:S}
\intertext{The equation of the plane $(S_0)$, which is parallel to 
this plane and passes through the origin, is}
  (S_0): &\quad& a x+b y+c z=0. \label{eq:S0}
\end{alignat}
Let
\[
\bm{a}=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\bm{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
\]
Then, equations \eqref{eq:S} and \eqref{eq:S0} are respectively
\begin{alignat}{2}
(S):   &\quad & (\bm{a}, \bm{x})=d \tag{\ref{eq:S}\textprime} \label{eq:S'}
\\
(S_0): &\quad & (\bm{a}, \bm{x})=0 \tag{\ref{eq:S0}\textprime} \label{eq:S0'}
\end{alignat}
and this equation \eqref{eq:S0'}

\end{document}



Thank you for editing my quastion and your answer. and thank you for enumerating my tex problem. When writing tex,  I'm going to check your answer! Thank you.
